# Instagram API лайк записи

Tags: php, ajax, instagram, бот, instagram-api

Пытаюсь разобраться с instagram API.
Мне нужен бот, который будет автоматически ставить всем моим подписчикам лайк.
Возился с instagram API, но там теперь токены проходят модернизацию и просто так не получить нужный мне токен.
Вопрос в том, как мне можно это реализовать, прошу направить меня.

Видел скрипты, как люди делали что то через AJAX запрос с куки

Comment: https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py - Изучайте. Вот только вапрос у вас не по теме.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а почему не по теме? Я спрашиваю потому что, чтобы в следующий раз не допускать такой ошибки

Comment: SDK для работы с Instagram API для PHP на [гитхабе](https://github.com/Andreyco/Instagram-for-PHP)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

Использую [это](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/), лайки ставятся [так](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API/blob/master/src/Request/Media.php#L151):

```
require ('../vendor/autoload.php');

$username = 'username';
$password = 'pass';
$debug = true;
$truncatedDebug = false;

$ig = new \InstagramAPI\Instagram($debug, $truncatedDebug);
$mediaId = '0123456789';

try {
    $ig->like($mediaId);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Something went wrong: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit(0);
}
```

P.S. Спасибо, что подсказали как правильно оформить.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov, ответ обновлён.